# Get a list of constants outside of PHP class

Tags: php, reflection, constants

I'm trying to get a list of all the constants that are defined outside of a PHP class but only if they start with a specific prefix (see [this tutorial](https://blog.liplex.de/use-reflection-in-php-to-get-enumeration-constants/)) and saw the [`ReflectionClass::getConstants`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.getconstants.php) functionality but this requires a class.

How do I achieve the same functionality if the constants are defined outside of a class?

Comment: Maybe try [`get_defined_constants`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-defined-constants.php)?

Comment: Thanks! An obvious solution eluded me.. I should hand my developer membership card now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the built-in function [`get_defined_constants`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-defined-constants.php). It will list all the constants even the ones coming from Core PHP and loaded extensions. You can pass `true` as the parameter to categorize them. To get just userland constants (both from `const` and from `define()`) use `get_defined_constants(true)['user']`

```
<?php

define('DEFINED_CONST', 'foo');
const myConst = 1;

print_r(get_defined_constants(true)['user']);
```

prints:

```
Array
(
    [DEFINED_CONST] => foo
    [myConst] => 1
)
```